# Keycloak with W3C Web Authentication(webAuthn) support for password-less authentication does not work on iOS

Tags: ios, safari, keycloak, webauthn

We are currently using **Keycloak 12.0.0** Passwordless login/authentication feature backed by W3C Web Authentication (webAuthn for password-less authentication).

We have bootstrapped an Identity Server using the same Authentication/Authorization provider, catering to **iOS/Android devices**.

I am able to customize authentication flow (through the admin console of keycloak). Using Keycloak's "JavaScript adapter" we are able to log-in on our Android app (using Chrome Custom Tabs - with fingerprint/device PIN). WebAuthn works great.

But on iOS 14 on Safari v14 it did not work as expected.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPEfa.jpg)

Here are screenshots of my configuration:

Authentication flows:

[Authentication flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAPtK.png)

[Authentication passwordless policy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8ZKF.png)

The same works on mac(macOS Big Sur 11.2.3) when run on Google chrome but not on safari v14.0.2
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Q1v4.png)

On October 19, 2020, Apple posted an explanation of their take on WebAuthn stating that Safari 14 to Support Biometric Authentication Via FIDO2 WebAuthn:

[Meet Face ID and Touch ID for the web](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10670/)

[webkit on iOS](https://webkit.org/blog/11312/meet-face-id-and-touch-id-for-the-web/)

Followed Keylock docs for webAuthn setup/configuration:
[Keycloak webAuthn](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#_webauthn)

Demo site for WebAuthn: [site](https://webauthn.io)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider using `ASWebAuthenticationSession` instead of `SFSafariViewController`, as stated [in Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/authenticating_a_user_through_a_web_service):

> A session that an app uses to authenticate a user through a web
> service.